# How to order dependencies/libraries in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android

In Android studio it was possible to remanage the order of dependencies and libraries (by moving them up or down inside a window) , but in Android Studio 4.1 I could not find any possibility for it. But I can't believe they removed this feature.

Thx for any hints.

Comment: Well, it is just a View (UI) of the `build.gradle` file. So you can adjsut them there. And the order does actually not matter.

Comment: I have got a modified Context.class (from package android.content) which shall be used. But android studio does automatically use the context.class from sdk (Android.jar). I once had managed to change the order, so it first used external dependencied than sdk library. But somehow I can't do it again. Can't find the window any more where I did reorder the dependencies.

Comment: The current problem is, I have to same classes with same package name, but android studio does not recognize the one from the external dependency.